# How to convince clients to upgrade to WCF or keep two code bases for Remoting and WCF

Tags: windows, wcf, sql-server-2008, version-control, deployment

Here is question for all those who have delivered
WCF solutions to their clients/customers where their customers
have some other old distributed technologies eg .net remoting/Asmx.

**Our situation**

**Technology for old suite of products** (Windows 2003)

Finance Back Office in ( .NET Remoting,Winforms, Webservices,SQL Server 2005)

Front Office (SQL 2005,ASP.NET)

**Technology for new suite of products** (Windows 2008)

Finance Back Office in (WCF,Winforms,some components WPF, Webservices,SQL Server 2008)

Front Office (SQL 2008,ASP.NET MVC and some components in silverlight)

1. Our new/expected customers  want our suite of products using real SOA (WCF) so we have migrated our products 
   (as they have systems from java world and would like to talk to our WCF services).
2. Some of our old customers who got .NET implementation of backoffice is serving well them from last 10 years, our products nicely settled in their enviornment happily chatting around their mainframes.(They are the one who are very reluctant to upgrade)
3. Existing customers are under impression it is a big technology stack change so they may need new hardware and definitely needs lot of testing efforts/resources to test new technology stack where actual benefit they are getting is small functionality which was done in last 6 months *but new features are must for them because of UK budget change.*

**Here are questions**

1) I need strong arguments for convienceing my old clients to upgrade to our new suite of products around following

- WCF      Over .Net Remoting
- SQL 2008     Over  SQL 2005
- Windows 2008    Over  Windows 2003

2) Are there (or will there) be any issues for keeping two code bases for Server side one for .Net remoting and another for WCF (if any body have successfully/unsuccessfully done it)

This might be the tricky case when some of our client still refuse to upgrade to new stack but we still have to deliver some of new features which were in RND
while we migrated to wcf.

Following will not be problem as we have good thoughts when we
started WCF

1) Obtaining proxies for Services are nicely seprated and easily replaceble for WCF and .net remoting.

2) Hosting shells are not issue as they are sperated nicely already.

If any one need more information please write back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general support from Microsoft for SQL 2005 has expired at April 12, 2011: http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=2855.

The general support from Microsoft for Windows 2003 has expired July 13, 2010: http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=3198.

.NET remoting is shipped with .NET Framework 1.1 and is considered legacy from .NET 2.0 onward. For .NET Framework 1.1 the .NET Remoting help in shown at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(v=vs.71).aspx. Now if you change the version for the same help file to .NET 3.0 (2.0 runtime) it is shown at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(v=VS.85).aspx which the first line statement:

> This topic is specific to a legacy technology that is retained for
>   backward compatibility with existing applications and is not
>   recommended for new development. Distributed applications should now
>   be developed using the Windows Communication Foundation (WCF).

These are usually good arguments for customers to start using newer platforms, because the lack of general support from Microsoft increases the risk of problems not being solved anymore with service packs or hotfixes and raises the cost of ownership of the product.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that two code bases is twice the work/maintenance.

Comment: +1 for the links they are useful , Any links\disucssions to support your statement ".NET remoting is shipped with .NET Framework 1.1 and is considered legacy from .NET 2.0 onward." thanks

Comment: Adjusted the answer to include sources of information for that .NET remoting statement

Comment: Thanks kroonwijk and Tim for your time :)